# How can you add a proxy when running azure functions locally - to access azure services like Cosmos/Storage/EventGrid?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventgrid

Currently i am trying to write an azure function in order to do some small operations against azure storage & azure event grid. My local machine is behind a corporate firewall. I am unable to configure azure storage or azure event grid to actually access the azure service to perform the operations.

I have tried creating an HTTP client handler - but instead i receive the "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times.' error when trying to override the send with my own HTTP client.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```cs
    public class TestCosmosDB
    {
        public TestCosmosDB()
        {
        }

        public void dosomething()
        {
            StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(Configuration.TableAccountName(), Configuration.TableAccountKey());
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
            TableClientConfiguration tableClientConfiguration = new TableClientConfiguration();

            SuperHandler superHandler = new SuperHandler();
            tableClientConfiguration.RestExecutorConfiguration.DelegatingHandler = superHandler;

            CloudTableClient tableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(tableClientConfiguration);
            CloudTable peopleTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(Configuration.TableName());
            TableQuery query = new TableQuery();
            TableContinuationToken token = null;

            TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity> result = peopleTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query,token).Result;
        }
    }

    public class SuperHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {

        protected  override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
            {
                request.Content = null;
            }

            HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            IWebProxy proxy = new ProxyTest(null);
            aHandler.Proxy = proxy;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(aHandler);
            return  client.SendAsync(request); 
        }
    }

    public class ProxyTest : IWebProxy
    {
        public Uri proxyUrl { get; set; }

        public ProxyTest(Uri uri)
        {
            proxyUrl = uri;
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            return proxyUrl;
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to install Fiddler to add the proxy ?